# Voyager language files can not translateable

Tags: laravel, voyager

[image]

I have tried the below commands

- `php artisan config:cache`
- `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Look at the red border I have drawn, The words don't show beauty

Answer (score 0):

Did you do db:seed using VoyagerDatabaseSeeder?

if so, check out your locale in config/app.php

if voyager doesn't support the locale it turns out like that.